# Building release CEF3 binaries, cross compilation of CEF3

Tags: linux, chromium-embedded

I build CEF3 following the [these](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/GeneralUsage#Building_from_Source_Code) and [these](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding) instructions.
I know I could download the prepackaged binaries, but I'm targeting to eventually use CEF3 on embedded system so I decided to build from source.

So after running these commands:

```
export GYP_GENERATORS='ninja'
cd /path/to/chromium/src/cef
./cef_create_projects.sh
cd /path/to/chromium/src
ninja -C out/Debug cefclient cef_unittests
```

I got the framework built in out/Debug directory with libcef.so's size more then 800 Mb (not stripped, with debug symbols apparently), after stripping it the size totaled to more then 190 Mb, which is still too much.

When I tried to run cefclient it crashed with this output:

> /home/alex/Documents/src/cef3/chromium/src/out/Debug/cefclient: symbol
>   lookup error:
>   /home/alex/Documents/src/cef3/chromium/src/out/Debug/lib/libcef.so:
>   undefined symbol:
>   _ZN5blink11WebViewImpl36setUseExternalPopupMenusThisInstanceEb

So the two main questions are:

1. How to build a release version of CEF3 with *ninja* build system with libcef.so of smaller size?
2. Why is cefclient crashing, as there were no errors at linking?

Please advise.

**EIDT:** I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04